# Give an example of a function $ f : [a,b] → \mathbb{R}$ that is continuous...

Tags: analysis

> Give an example of a function $ f : [a,b] → \mathbb{R}$ that is continuous, and a sequence $(f(x_n))$ converging to $\sup(f([a,b]))$, but for which $(x_n)$ does not converge.

I am having trouble coming up with an example, especially one that converges to $\sup$. Any and all help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For instance, you can take the constant function $f(x) = 1$ for all $x\in [a,b]$, and $x_n = \begin{cases} a &\text{ if } n \text{ even}\\ b &\text{ if } n \text{ odd}\end{cases}$.

Comment: More generally, you can do a similar construction for any function whose maximum is reached at at least two distinct points.